# StackExchange™ SuperCollider Freehand Circle™ Editor - [Now supported on EVERY StackExchange site!]

Tags: script, meta

### Update Jul 2015:

[The author is not able to update anymore](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange%E2%84%A2-supercollider-freehand-circle%E2%84%A2-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment11144_2177). Use [Freehand Circles Drawing Tool](https://stackapps.com/q/6353/29559) instead.

---

---

> ## Important:
>
> ---
>
> **All SE sites** (with one exception - see below) **are now supported.** Please upgrade to the latest version to enjoy this wonderful new feature!
>
> A special thank you to [Jacob Jernigan](https://serverfault.com/users/60820/jacob) for donating space and bandwidth to host the images generated by this script.
>
> Please make sure you update to the latest version as soon as possible.

**v1.2 Update** - *what's new*:
- Images are now stored on permanent server
- **All** StackExchange sites are now supported (Ask Ubuntu is *technically* supported but has CSS issues)

**v1.1 Update** - *what's new*:
- Fixed bug where answer would have long blank section
- Added new color and brush settings
- Images must be clicked on first to activate tools
- Added support for annotating images when composing an answer / question
- Fixed `fkey` bug

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/905708658.png

**Also,** you can find an old video demonstrating its use [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/videos/circles.html).

### About

I humbly present to you one of the most remarkable accomplishments: a UserScript that makes drawing Freehand Circles™ extremely easy!

You can install this UserScript in your browser. After installation, you will be able to draw freehand circles freely on any image in a post! But that's not all - you can also save the changes you've made merely by clicking the 'save' button.

You can find some technical details [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/freehand-circle-code-description).

#### License

The MIT License

#### Download

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/circles.user.js

#### Platform

Any browser that can run / install UserScripts.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

JavaScript on the client side, PHP on the server

Comment: Note that to be really effective you should have edit privileges on the site in question, else you still enter the regular edit queue.

Comment: @dra: That's a good point! But it'll still work as expected in that case.

Comment: What happens to the original image?

Comment: @jjnguy: Nothing... they vanish forever :P Actually, they get replaced with the modified one. They'll still show in the revision list.

Comment: @Shog9: There's some below now.

Comment: If you lack inspiration on stuff to FHC, google "people of wal mart"

Comment: What kind of PHP script are we talking about here?

Comment: @Earlz: It's a short 58 line script that overlays the source image with the circles and sends it to imgur. Source here: http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/circles/process.txt

Comment: @Earlz: Please excuse my awful coding style and comments :) Oh, you'll also need to quickly get an API key (it hardly takes a second and it's anonymous). http://imgur.com/register/api_anon

Comment: @George, why do you send it to imgur? Why not save it to the server this PHP script runs on, or better yet, use a static web host(usually providing gigs of space for nearly free) to host these images (and instead upload there?)

Comment: @Earlz: 'Cuz I don't have that :) Plus imgur has much better latency.

Comment: @George, good point. I may in the future be willing to donate some space and bandwidth, but that won't help with latency (though I get good ping times of 17ms from my server to my house, a few hundred miles away). Anyway, considered using DropBox maybe? It has a PHP API and public URLs.  Or searching for an image hosting service which doesn't rate limit an API key?

Comment: @Earlz: I'll take a look at DropBox.

Comment: You can contact me also George, depending on your needs I could probably help you out.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: add a clear button for when some of us have trouble drawing circles. :x

Comment: @The: I used your website's contact form to send you a message.

Comment: George, bug report: Using the script throws a lolcat error. According to @balpha, the fkey was changed. `no, that's the XSRF token. just tell him to use StackExchange.options.user.fkey`  http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/569875#569875 hope that helps

Comment: @What: Okay, I'll have that fixed soon.

Comment: @Pekka: Please update the script when you get a chance - I changed the hosting for the images now.

Comment: If anyone is interested, it is *extremely* easy to convert this into a Safari extension. You add it as an end script, set up the allowed domains, and modify the script to not do anything unless it is on a question page (since extensions can only be directly limited to domains, not paths).

Comment: @Pekka: This is now supported on **all** StackExchange sites!

Comment: A *really* interesting addition to this would be adding a button to the markdown editor that automatically inserts an empty canvas to draw on without having to upload anything. I'd try building it myself if I had the time, but I'm up to my ears in work... Is there a place to place Stackapps requests? Meta?

Comment: @Pekka: Well the precedent has been to simply post it as an answer to the question. So feel free to post it below.

Comment: @Pekka: If you like this script, you'll definitely like [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2444/flackbot-making-conversation-in-the-chat-rooms) app.

Comment: @George older images with links to the quickmediasolutions.com don't work any more - they get a login dialog. Example: [Hide answer bodies in careers profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/88786) is there anything we can do? Do these images have a new home?

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks for the heads up. I'll have to talk to Jacob since that particular subdomain points to his server. Hopefully he knows what's going on.

Comment: `fhc.quickmediasolutions.com` doesn't seem to be working any more. Is there any chance to recover existing old images from it?

Comment: @Pekka: I'll speak to Jacob about that.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Nice. But it does not work on Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.57 m). (tampermonkey)

Comment: I think this post will need to simply become historical. I don't have the time to maintain the script anymore and it never really served a tangibly practical purpose.

Comment: There appears to be a missing image in this question. Any idea what it was or where it is now?

Comment: @NathanOsman Can I have the code please?

Comment: @Mew I finally found it and posted it here: https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/620001a7b0084d154093

Comment: all the links are broken

Comment: @NathanOsman I've made another script: http://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088 You might want to check it out! :)

Comment: @Ooker Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/620001a7b0084d154093). You can also directly install it with a user script manager that supports `.user.js` files by clicking [here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/620001a7b0084d154093/raw/3fd5a55c61aeb77e84d4159c6e93553c1f1bf91e/circles.user.js).

Answer (score 25):

## Here's a sandbox. Go nuts, you crazy kids.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: that bunny is great!

Comment: How much time does this supposed to take ? It;'s taking pretty long fore me...

Answer (score 13):

Nice, but: you're not using the SE provided Imgur account?

But then you're basically introducing image rot?

For [free accounts](https://imgur.com/faq#long):

> How long do you keep the images?
>
> As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 3 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images.

(Note that a view is a request by a browser that is not using an image from its cache. Imgur tells browsers to cache a full year. I doubt Google indexing will keep refreshing the view count? Of course, unless edited by the OP within the grace period, the post revision history will still refer to the first image, which is probably hosted on the SE provided account.)

Comment: Good point. The perfect solution for this would be for the system to use SO's imgur account...

Comment: @Pekka: That's impossible, I'm afraid... since the images are uploaded with a separate PHP script. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @George yeah, I feared as much. Too bad

Comment: I think you're assuming images made with this *should* be archived forever...

Comment: True, @mmyers, but I think the original images should be preserved. Like I wrote: the revision history will show the author's original image if someone else added freehand circles at a later time. But even then: not too nice if a post shows no image at all without going into the revision history?

Comment: @Pekka, @Arjan: This is no longer a problem. See the update above.

Comment: @NathanOsman I still don't understand why do you refrain from using StackExchange imgur storage. Once the server you use is down, all the images will be gone.

Answer (score 8):

I can't make this extension to work: is it outdated?

Comment: The server-side of the script is currently broken. There is an attempt to bring it back up, so I will post details here as I have them.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison such a pity, it was awesome! And for the first time I was using it for something useful :)

Comment: @George Yeah--I loaded it and it gives me `There was an error retrieving the new image URL.` :(

Comment: Hey George, I'm assuming this is still broken?  It looks like an awesome script, in fact, I'm surprised SE hasn't taken this and made it an actual feature. How cool!  ..... `Uncaught ReferenceError: Attacklab is not defined how-to-run-nodejs-on-linux-platform (1):17
Failed to load resource http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/process.php`

Comment: @Manishearth You may be interested in this: http://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088

Answer (score 5):

There you have it, the **George Edison Free Hand Circle Badge!**

I promised him I'd suggest a badge if he pulled this off.

[image]

Here's the badge:

[image]

Comment: @George - I didn't have _many_ options ...

Comment: You do now.

Comment: @TimPost if you want, I can jQuery that badge for :P

Comment: @Manishearth `$('#badge').freeHandCircle(point1, point2, point3, point4, color, text, callback())` Could it be so easy? I smell an ego stroking userscript coming on!!

Comment: @TimPost Made a (simple) badge. I personally prefer `$(".badge").attr("contenteditable",true).attr("href","").attr("name","")` and then use Paint ;-)

Answer (score 5):

After a day's testing (and my [first real-world use!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/81589/top-x-in-profile/81590#81590)) I can see the need for three features that would be really great to have:

- An eraser — might be half-way easy to implement? I don't know.
- A reset button next to the "Save" button.
- Maybe a **very small** text link pointing to the original image underneath the edited image?
- One **bug**: If you leave the image's canvas while pressing the mouse button, and release the button outside the canvas, the script will not recognize that drawing has ended. The next time you mouse over the image, it will go on drawing. No idea whether anything can be done about that — maybe end drawing mode if the mouse cursor leaves the canvas?

Comment: @Pekka: Good idea. An undo button would be pretty easy - a reset button even easier. As for the original image... wouldn't that be in the revision history?

Comment: @George it would, but depending on how, where and for what this is going to be used, there may be the need for users to quickly get hold of an image without having to go through the revision history (like in order to sketch an alternative suggestion).

Comment: @Pekka: I see what you're saying... but getting previous revisions using the API *for every answer on the page* would be very expensive.

Comment: @George but would the previous image's URL not be available from fetching it before it was drawn on, and re-inserting into the updated post? (Mind you, despite understanding the basic concept I'm still largely ignorant of how this works, so this is just me speculating)

Comment: @Pekka: Are you asking if it would be possible to view the previous version of the image *before* you save your changes? **That** would be possible and pretty easy.

Comment: @George no, I mean when the new, drawn-on image is saved, adding a tiny, tiny link to the original image (which usually is on imgur) underneath the end result so people can more easily copy it (and paste it into their answer, and draw on it).

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks! That's exactly what I'll do - if the mouse leaves the canvas, it'll end drawing operations. That's a cinch to add.

Comment: @Pekka: I implemented two of your suggestions (the one with the mouse leaving the canvas and the reset button). Simply use the same link in the question above to update.

Answer (score 1):

## No f****ing way.

This is *brilliant*. And the auto-save-to-imgur-and-replace-the-link-thingy is *genius*.

[image]

Community canvas: <s>(note the current limitation that an image can be edited only once)</s>
[image]

Comment: I knew it would get people excited! And it's so simple to use too!

Comment: @George, I'm getting this error when trying to edit the above image - "There was an error retrieving the imgur.com URL."

Comment: @jjnguy: Unfortunately, it has come to my attention that the same image cannot be edited twice. I'm working on that, but in the meantime, feel free to post your own image and try it.

Comment: @George, is this meant to work on stackapps? It only works on MSO for me.

Comment: @Jonathan: Only meant for Meta.

Comment: @George, oh right just wondered how people were drawing here,btw it goes without saying that this script is bloody amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

Bug:

If an SE dialog pops up (vote to close/flag/&c), the script kicks in and blocks clicking.

[image]

Clicking just puts it into FHC draw mode.

Test case: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/128528/benefactor-badge-awarded-twice

Answer (score 0):

Add your circle around the painted pixel and (400,400), and the second one around the first one, and so on -- how many can we fit?

[image]

Comment: This alone will use up my API requests :(

Comment: @George, is that what "There was an error retrieving revision content." means?

Comment: @Nick: Hmmm... that means there was an error getting the latest revision for the post. I'll see if I can reproduce that.

Comment: @Nick: Yup, I can reproduce... looking into it now.

Comment: Ooops... now the post got rolled back. *Sigh...*

Comment: Are those boobs?

Comment: @Juan No it's mesmerizing glasses.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some image service/URL thing where you can get a blank canvas to then draw on it, a-la Placekitten (but without the ugly cats)?

`http://placekitten.com/500/100`
[image]

Comment: Well, Placekitten without the ugly cats would probably be http://placehold.it/

Comment: (I'm getting an "Access Restricted" for that image, and the entire [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com) website. The page source has an odd iframe, referring to `http://anti-virus.cloudflare.com`. That company apparently also [protects against hotlinking](http://www.cloudflare.com/plans.html), which seems to be odd for this very service. I can still get there [using Web Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://placekitten.com&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0) and then get totally different HTML. Maybe my IP has been blocked due to the above hotlinking? Odd!)

Comment: @Arjan: You won't now... :)

Comment: (I got a blank page yesterday, @George, but now I get [a virus warning](http://i.imgur.com/R7WEM.png). It's telling me *"This IP address has been seen posting comment or blog spam"*, while earlier I guessed it was caused by some blocking I do myself, or by using a non-compatible browser or OS. I don't think I like that *"This website is participating in a project to stop attacks and educate visitors with infected computers about how they can clean up their machines"* if it is indeed throwing false positives. Right now, the scary cat bothers me more! ;-) But I'll investigate later...)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm not responsible for either of those domains.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we're now obliged to submit all our screen grabs in 3D, and to assist with this our FHC should also be 3D:

> [3... 2... 1... until George Edison's FHC script gets 3D effects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/126355/layout-of-annotated-posts-is-broken-in-firefox-11#comment342385_126355)

That would make this truly rainbow unicorn awesome or something ;)

Comment: [I don't know what you're talking about :P](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zGB.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Bug Report

If you try to flag a question with an image, and the window overlaps with the image, the flag popup is unable to be navigated.