# George the Dev - Making Conversation in the Chat Rooms

Tags: app, chat, golang

### Screenshot

[image: George in action!]

### About

George the Dev is a chat bot for the Stack Exchange network of chat sites.

He currently hangs out in the [Sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) and is capable of understanding a few commands and those commands resemble a natural form of English. Here are some examples:

```
Me: @GeorgetheDev what time is it?
George: @Nathan The current time is Thu, 03 Sep 2015 05:22:02 GMT.
Me: @GeorgetheDev what is tritium?
George: @Nathan [link to "Tritium" article on Wikipedia]
Me: @GeorgetheDev what is (12 + 2) * 3?
George: @Nathan 42
```

He can also lookup manpages, perform `ping` and `dig` lookups, etc.

#### License

George is released under the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

#### Download

The source code for George is available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/nathan-osman/george-the-dev-bot).

### Contact

I can be contacted at `nathan@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

The bot is written in Go and uses [go-sechat](https://stackapps.com/questions/7245/go-sechat-go-package-for-interacting-with-the-stack-exchange-chat-network).

Comment: @Fosco: Well... me too. I will do my best to make this happen - currently some proprietary API keys are what's holding up the project from going open source.

Comment: Nice work!!!!!!!

Comment: pretty cool stuff

Comment: How did you code that?