# Freehand Circles Drawing Tool

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### What is it?

A userscript that lets you draw directly onto images on any Stack Exchange site to add [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/260841) (or anything else you might like to add).

It has been designed to work like [StackExchange™ SuperCollider Freehand Circle™ Editor - [Now supported on EVERY StackExchange site!]](https://stackapps.com/q/2177/26088) which unfortunately the owner [doesn't have time to maintain anymore](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange%e2%84%a2-supercollider-freehand-circle%e2%84%a2-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment11144_2177) :(

### How do I use it?

On every image on every site you will now see 2 buttons added: `edit` and `save`.

Clicking `edit` converts the image to a canvas for you to draw on. A toolbar is added underneath the image where you can change the brush **colour** or brush *width**. Once you are done, you can click `save` and the script will upload the new image to imgur, and edit the post for you with the new link in it!

Note: You **must have** an access token for this to work. Get one [at Github](http://shu8.github.io/Freehand-Circles-Drawing-Tool/)

### Install

1. You need to have something like [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) or [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) for this to work, as it saves your access token via `GM_setValue()`!
2. You need an access token. Get one [from here](http://shu8.github.io/Freehand-Circles-Drawing-Tool/)
3. Install: <kbd>[view source](https://github.com/shu8/Freehand-Circles-Drawing-Tool/blob/master/freehandCircles.user.js)</kbd> or <kbd>[install](https://github.com/shu8/Freehand-Circles-Drawing-Tool/raw/master/freehandCircles.user.js)</kbd>

[image]

### Notes

1. Images are save under imgur.com and NOT stack.imgur.com (Stack Exchange's own domain for inline images). This shouldn't be a problem because it [says here](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201476457-How-long-do-you-keep-the-images-) that images are kept forever...
2. The script works thanks to [Fabric.JS](http://fabricjs.com/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
3. This script has only been tested on Google Chrome and Firefox - I haven't tested on other browsers!
4. [Here is a sandbox where you can test the script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/259022#259022)

[image]

---

## Change log

v1.0.6: Fixed the script - it was broken with new images [that are now linked to a bigger version automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261180/260841).

Comment: For what? Demonstrating the script? It might also be worth noting that this will not work GIFs - it can't edit a gifs frame!

Comment: hey, look at what I did http://stackapps.com/questions/6216/inline-editor-regardless-of-reputation :D

Comment: @nicael I've already upvoted before :) But what have you done to that gif!?

Comment: Double-gifed :D

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

Unfortunately for me the buttons appear in the wrong place (at the far right of the screen next to the scrollbar:

[image]

Please let me know if you need any more info to help debug this.

OS Windows 7 64 bit.

Firefox 38.0.5

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

As per comment buttons abscure the image:

[image]

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (there was an error with the access token)

When saving (which doesn't work) I get:

[image]

---

Without freehand:

[image]

With freehand enabled:

[image]

---

Comment: Those are a lot of userscripts! One last thing before I start checking the code: can you disabling them? The main ones are SOUP, Comment Separator Fix and Threading comments? Those *might* be conflicting (or it might just be my bad CSS :)

Comment: All 3 disabled, no change. I assume I don't need to restart browser but just reload page (which I did)?

Comment: Never mind! I've reproed it in Firefox. I'll see what I can do! When it's fixed, I'll give you a ping :) But till then, you can use the functionality of the script! Just not the design... :( I think it's the `right:10px;` causing it - but as I said on Meta - I can't update anything today! I will do ASAP though :)

Comment: After a closer look I see a small problem. The edit andsavebuttons are on top of (so obscuring the image) :( Question updated with new screenshot. In addition the save button is often not working ... eventual error along the line of image upoad not working or something.

Comment: Hmmm.. I didn't think of that! I'll relocate the buttons ASAP. BTW when it fails, could you please check in the console whether there was an error - that way I can tell you what exactly is the problem! Thanks :)

Comment: 2 warnings in the console after I click save (and nothing gets saved). See screenshot.

Comment: OK - I receive that as well, and I don't think I can do anything about that. However, is there a `Network` tab in Firefox's dev tools? If so, can you go on that, *then* click save, and look at anything red or that's errorred out? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25259/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-).

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to update you - I looked into SOUP's changes and couldn't find anything that would cause the image to change size... However I just though of another place I might be able to check to see how to fix it - I'll get back to you by tomorrow

Comment: BTW Would it be possible for you to raise an issue at Github? It's much easier to manage over there! :)

Comment: Nope sorry - I still can't see which fix causes the bug!

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

---

This looks really neat! I'm glad to see that someone has brought my original idea back to life and your code looks a lot cleaner and simpler than mine :)

I tried running the script with Greasemonkey in Firefox 38.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 but wasn't able to get it to run out-of-the-box. I was able to make an adjustment to get it running, however.

`jQuery` (and consequently `$`) are not available to the script, so it runs into errors as soon as it hits the first line. Although in older versions of Greasemonkey, you could simply do:

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
```

...this no longer works and it is far easier to simply include jQuery itself in the script:

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
```

(That line should be added right after the `@match` directives.)

Comment: Whenever I **require** jQuery, everything breaks in Chrome! Which is why I generally leave it out and let Tampermonkey use SE's jQuery. However, I just installed Firefox, so I will try it out... bear with me :)

Comment: How exactly does Chrome break?

Comment: OK - it works in Firefox and Chrome if I `require` Fabric.JS and `require` jQuery... I swear that wasn't working this morning!

Comment: I've updated the script - please can you update and check if it works now? Thanks :)

Comment: You can update now to get multiple brush colours and a slider to change the brush thickness :)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - fixed in v1.0.7

---

Now, you can't seem to be able to change it properly if you use the new `[![][1]][1]` format.

Try it here:

[image]

However, if you use the old format, it still works:

[image]

Comment: _Blech it edited both images because they use the same source?_

Comment: Hmm, I thought this was fixed in v1.0.6 (see the change log), but I'll check to see if it hasn't :/ Bit busy today, so might be tomorrow! :)

Comment: Fixed in v1.0.7 (was broken for Firefox only)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The buttons cover images in tags:
[image]
You just can't see the tag or the image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-ruby-client)'s the tag.

Comment: images in tags!? Didn't know that existed! I'll try to look at it and push an update out in the next few days :)

Comment: I've updated the script at github